# CTreeCtrl::SetItemState function has got issue in VS 2013

Tags: c++, mfc

With the same code, VS2008 and VS2013 gave different results. Hidden line was moved to the right in VS2013.

```
HTREEITEM hItemPartSets = m_wndBlockTree.InsertItem( _T("Big Block"), 0, 0, NULL);
HTREEITEM hItemDefault = m_wndBlockTree.InsertItem( _T("Default"), 0, 0, NULL);
m_wndBlockTree.SetItemState(hItemDefault, INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(2), TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
HTREEITEM hItemProperties = m_wndBlockTree.InsertItem( _T("By Properties"), 0, 0, NULL);
m_wndBlockTree.SetItemState(hItemProperties, INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(2), TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
HTREEITEM hItemMaterials = m_wndBlockTree.InsertItem( _T("By Materials"), 0, 0, NULL);
m_wndBlockTree.SetItemState(hItemMaterials, INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(2), TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
HTREEITEM hItemElement = m_wndBlockTree.InsertItem( _T("By Element"), 0, 0, NULL);
m_wndBlockTree.SetItemState(hItemElement, INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(2), TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
```

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Comment: While entering your question, you see a live preview of it. Please edit your question and apply proper formatting.

Comment: Thanks. I will follow your suggestion next time.